# Where to put scripts/executables that will be called in the application

Tags: java

I have a vbscript that my Windows-only application uses. I call it using Runtime `exec`

```
wscript my_script.vbs
```

And it works.

Now I want to distribute the application as a jar. Where should I put the script?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think of a folder called `resources` or `scripts` that would be at the same level as your `src` or `bin` folders.

Answer (score 0):

Include the file in your JAR.  The first time you need it, copy it from the JAR:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("my_script.vbs");
```

And store it in the Application Data directory:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Application Data/MyApp/my_script.vbs");
```

Run it as needed from there.